# Move / Drag window with Qt::FramelessWindowHint

Tags: c++, qt

I applied the following flags to my windows:

```
w.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```

How can I make my window "draggable" with mouse ? I mean, holding left click to move window like normal apps. I removed the title bar to add my own one.

Thanks.

Comment: Already saw it but I don't understand what they mean...

Comment: There is not much to add, the linked answer has a working code solution in it. If there is something specific you don't understand, open another question on that specific thing.